# Spring @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) doesn't ensure spring run first

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have 2 `@Component` classes: `AppConfig` that loads properties from Consul server and `JpaConfig` that uses `env` that I set via properties loaded by `@Bean` in `AppConfig`. So there are 2 beans:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
Void consulProperties() {
    //setting environment...
}
```

And second in `JpaConfig`:

```
@Bean
// @DependsOn("consulProperties")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    //some more logic

    return factoryBean;
}
```

This doesn't work without `@DependsOn("consulProperties")`. It starts initiate before `consulProperties`, at the time when environment isn't set yet .All other beans seem to wait for `consulProperties` fine... Why? What to I do wrong? Is it `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`-specific functionality? How to make sure a bean to run first of all without specifying `@DependsOn`?

Comment: It isn't a bean it should be registered as an additional `PropertySource` using an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Comment: It couldn't be done this way because it needs logic with specifying url, token and mapping consul properties to environment properties.

Comment: Yes it can. I said you need a `PropertySource` I didn't say you need a `@PropertySource`. Basically what you are doing inside your `@Bean` method should be in your custom `PropertySource` (or `ApplicationContextInitializer`) and registered through the `Environment`.

Comment: Can you share code with what just you mentioned: (url, token, etc). I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: @M.Deinum I put it in `Evironment` but in bean method. I got what you mean, thanks, will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to materialize `consulProperties()` as bean (not an `Void` type) and inject it in `entityManagerFactory()` method as parameter.